# Can you guess the name of Jim's girlfriend?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, chemistry

Ben and Jim are best friends and like playing pranks among themselves. Once Ben sent a fake phishing link to Jim to know his girlfriend's name but Jim was clever and instead of entering his girlfriend's name, he entered a code that was sent to Ben's email account. The code was

> 9801

After 5 minutes he received an email from Jim, reading:

> "Give her an IUSPAC name and find her name if you can"

Hint:

> Jim is really nuts about chemistry.

Can you guess his girlfriend's name?

Comment: I'm guessing IUSPAC is an anagram: http://anagram-solver.net/IUSPAC ...

Comment: @mestackoverflow, Nice try but it ain't an anagram

Comment: @mestackoverflow iUPAC is a naming convention for organic chemical compounds (Jim is really nuts about chemistry), not sure if the extra S is intentional or typo

Comment: probably "Amy", "Polly" it not populare any more.

Comment: pubchem 9801 is prenylamine - not sure if that helps.

Comment: @Jasen I was literally just about to comment that :P

Comment: A [search](https://oeis.org/search?q=9801) gave me 284 results containing 9801. Is any of them close?

Comment: ISPAC  is International Society for Polycyclic Aromatic Compounds.  Can't find IUSPAC.

Comment: 9801=3*3*3*3*11*11

Comment: ispac is also International Symposium on Polymer Analysis and Characterization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it ennnoctnilun?? I'm just guessing.

Comment: If so, she has some cruel parents.

Comment: Right, I don't know what the answer would be.

Comment: I was looking for "Eonu" though you gave her full name. I will mark it right,

Comment: So, no solution?

Answer (score 0):

After searching for some chemistry  details

> Found nothing about IUSPAC (May be some hint)
>
>  IUPAC : the IUPAC nomenclature of 
>  organic chemistry is a systematic 
>  method of naming organic chemical
>  compounds as recommended by 
>  the International Union of Pure and
>  Applied Chemistry (IUPAC)
>
>  Number 9801 is a pubchemID(dont 
>  know what that is)  of:
>  **PRENYLAMINE**
>
>  whose IUPAC name is
>  **3,3-diphenyl-N-(1-phenylpropan-2-yl)propan-1-amine**
>
>  Also looked for some synonyms of that:
>
>  So found 4 synonyms
>  Corontin
>  Difril
>  Prenylamine
>  Segontin
>
>  (Out of which no one seems like a girls name)

Dont know what to do after this. May be this may help in further answers.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess. As others have noted

> PubChem CID 9801 is prenylamine.
>  The chemical formula for prenylamine is: $C_{24} H_{27} N$.
>  If we rotate C by 24 places, we get A. Rotate H by 27 places gives I.
>  Putting this together gives AIN, which is an Arabic girls' name.
>  This, of course, ignores the IUSPAC part of the puzzle.
>  The wording suggests that maybe the answer is to give the IUSPAC name
>  of the compound as well as the girlfriend's name. If so, then as others have
>  noted, the IUPAC (assuming this is what is meant) name of prenylamine is 3,3-diphenyl-N-(1-phenylpropan-2-yl)propan-1-amine.

Comment: shouldn't we rotate N by 1 place?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I considered that. It isn't usually written with a subscript, so I didn't rotate. I actually hope this isn't the real answer because it isn't very satisfying.